# Flutter widget test: find.byKey does not work if widget have key: GlobalKey(debugLabel: "gridView")

Tags: flutter

If I use GlobalKey for some widget

```dart
final gridBuilder = GridView.builder(
      itemCount: movies.length,
      key: GlobalKey(debugLabel: "gridView"),
```

I can not access my GridView while testing by calling

```dart
find.byKey(Key('gridView'));
```

nether

```dart
find.byKey(GlobalKey(debugLabel: "gridView"));
```

Any solution except finding by type or text?

Answer (score 10):

I'm running into the same problem here, did you find a way to get around properly?

Didn't find any other way to preserve the `GlobalKey` on the widget than wrapping it in a `Container` and giving it a `Key`:

```dart
final Container gridBuilder = Container(
  key: Key('gridView'),
  child: GridView.builder(
    itemCount: movies.length,
    key: GlobalKey(),
  ),
);
```

Then in your test you can access the `GridView` this way:

```dart
find.descendant(of: find.byKey(Key('gridView')), matching: find.byType(GridView));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. the @jordan LL solution as perfect!!!  As a workaround, i've used tha follow strategy:
Instead use:
`var key1 = find.byKey(ValueKey(key'$OVERVIEW_GRID_ITEM_FAVORITE_BUTTON_KEY\_0'));`

I have workedaroung using:
`var key1  = find.descendant( of: find.byKey(Key('$OVERVIEW_GRID_ITEM_FAVORITE_BUTTON_KEY\_0')), matching: find.byType(OverviewGridItem));`