# Flutter DataRow.key does not show key for find.byKey Widget Testing

Tags: flutter, dart, widget-test-flutter, flutter-datatable

I'm writing widget tests for a Flutter app. I have a `DataTable` that I'm trying to test, but when I try to find a specific `DataRow` by the `ValueKey` I've assigned, I get the error:

```
Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _KeyFinder:<zero widgets with key [<'row_1685964365554x393824037782945800'>]>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected
```

To diagnose the issue, I simplified the test by creating a plain DataTable in my test file. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

class Item {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String type;
  
  Item({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.type,
  });
}

const kKeyValueToFind = "1685964365554x393824037782945800";
List<Item> _createItems() {
  return <Item>[
    Item(
      id: kKeyValueToFind,
      name: "kimchee",
      type: "food",
    ),
    Item(
      id: "1679537663980x853624879356837900",
      name: "Pizza dough",
      type: "food",
    ),
    Item(
      id: "1678726754135x305030564311466000",
      name: "Guava juice",
      type: "drink",
    )
  ];
}

Widget _createTestWidget(List<Item> items) {
  return Builder(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: DataTable(
            columns: const <DataColumn>[
              DataColumn(label: Text('col1')),
              DataColumn(label: Text('col2')),
            ],
            rows: items
                .map(
                  (e) => DataRow(
                    cells: <DataCell>[
                      DataCell(
                        Text(
                          key: ValueKey('cell1_${e.id}'),
                          e.name,
                        ),
                      ),
                      DataCell(
                        Text(
                          key: ValueKey('cell2_${e.id}'),
                          e.type,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                    key: ValueKey('row_${e.id}'),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}

void main() {
  late List<Item> items;
  
  setUp(() {
    items = _createItems();
  });
  
  group('DataTable key test', () {
    
    testWidgets('Should find a DataTable row by id', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // arrange
      await tester.pumpWidget(_createTestWidget(items));
      debugDumpApp();
      
      // act
      var rowFinder = find.byKey(const Key('row_$kKeyValueToFind'));
      
      // assert
      expect(rowFinder, findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

You can also [view it in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/193f7e1b14b114063f9ce2b57aeb5c7e?).

Similar to my initial tests, running `debugDumpApp()` shows the widget tree *without* the specified key for any DataRows. You can see the output of the `debugDumpApp()` call as part of my related gist, [here](https://gist.github.com/chrischiaro/193f7e1b14b114063f9ce2b57aeb5c7e#file-debugdumpapp_output-txt).

I've searched SO, but haven't found any questions that deal with this issue or help me resolve it. The closest posts I found are probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67434331/dart-flutter-widget-test-text-widgets-are-not-found-either-by-key-nor-by-text), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74767898/how-flutters-find-finds-widget-on-widget-testing), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56079311/flutter-widget-test-find-bykey-does-not-work-if-widget-have-key-globalkeydebu).

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Or do you think this is a bug with Flutter? I found [this bug report from April 2020](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54651) that was closed without being resolved, and it seems to deal with this exact issue.

I'm hoping it's just something I'm doing wrong, as that will be a lot easier to fix.